# to where or towards where

Tags: prepositions

Is the following sentence correct?

> She drew his attention **to** where there was the duster.

I feel there has to be "**towards**", not "**to**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**to** specifies a place

**towards** specifies a direction

So your sentence should be:

> She drew his attention to where the duster was.

or

> She drew his attention towards the duster.